# Best way to store multiple lists of true false values

Tags: c#, performance, storage, bitarray

This is just to settle a curiosity - Suppose, in my C# project, I have a list containing millions of strings, each along the following lines:

```
"123Hi1234Howdy"
"Hi1Howdy23"
....
```

And all I need to know is, for each character in the string, if it is a digit or is it a letter.

So, I was thinking the easiest way to store this would be as 0's and 1's or True / False. So, in the example above, assuming I could assign `IsLetter = 1` and `IsDigit = 0`, I could transform each line to:

```
"123Hi1234Howdy"  >> 00011000011111
"Hi1Howdy23"      >> 1101111100
....
```

That **seems to me** to be the most efficient way to store the data I'm looking for (but please do already correct me if I'm wrong on this - I'm still pretty much a newbie with programming).

So, writing the code that loops through a line and checks for whether each character is a digit or a letter and converting it to true/false or 1/0 is easy enough. My question is what would be the best way to store each line's output?

Should I store each line's output as a bit array? Could it be stored as some other type (maybe, say, integer) that could then be converted back to a series of bits? Should it be stored as a boolean array?
Any other thoughts on the best way to store this? When it's all said and done, I need to have a list where I can know, for example:

```
myList[0] = 00011000011111
myList[1] = 1101111100
```

And, then, therefore `myList[0] <> myList[1]`

Comment: You should add a description of what/why constitutes "best" in your scenario

Comment: Why do you need to know whether a given character is a letter or a digit? Depending on what you need that information for, you could compress things even further. Note that manipulating bit arrays is not necessarily fast -- the smallest representation doesn't automatically mean the fastest algorithm.

Comment: Depending on string length, you could convert to a number and store that, but it will only work on strings below 64 characters.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I updated my question slightly, the real aim here is simply to be able to know how many different strings I have in my list based on the `isDigit` / `IsLetter` criteria.

Comment: @AlexK., I apologize and edited the question slightly, my main aim here is simply to be able to know how many different / unique strings I have in my list based on the `isDigit` / `IsLetter` criteria and, then, to know what each one actually is later on (simply the `0` and `1` representation).

Comment: Yes, as CaffGeek said you can use an array of Integers or Longs depending on the String length if it is less than 64 characters and use bitwise operations to turn on/off the bits that you need to. Otherwise, I would use an array of [BitArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)

Comment: I still think more info is needed, i.e How are you going to use the stored representations?  Are you wanting to reduce the size of the stored map or optimize it for something, if so what?

Comment: If you only need to know how many different strings you have modulo letter/digit conversion, there is no need to store them at all, or at least no need to worry about how efficiently you store them unless you expect a lot of uniques. Convert the strings as you've indicated (to strings), then maintain a dictionary of counts keyed on the converted strings. The number of unique strings is `dictionary.Values.Sum()`.

Comment: @AlexK., I was trying not to over-complicate the question - I am still trying to learn and, so, create fake challenges for myself to see how I would do something - I saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35989564/1693085 and was wondering, in the simplest scenario, simply replacing digits for "\d" and letters for "[A-Z]", what could be a cool way to do this... Find uniques, then do the replacement after the fact.

Comment: *`dictionary.Count`, obviously. `dictionary.Values.Sum()` is the number of all strings.

Comment: A lot of discussion could be made about this issue. It is too broad. Big set of trade-offs. The right solution depends very much on the concrete use case (which does not exist as this is a training question). I like the question but I have to vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `BitArray` for each word and set the bits to true or false if they are a digit or not.  See this possible solution:

```
void Main()
{
    string[] words = 
    {
        "123Hi1234Howdy", 
        "Hi1Howdy23"
    };

    //Create an array of BitArray
    var bArrays = words.Select(w => new BitArray(w.Select(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()));

    //You can also create string too
    var strings = words.Select(w => new string(w.Select(c => char.IsDigit(c) ? '1' : '0').ToArray())).ToArray();


}
```

This is not necessarily the fastest or most efficient.  I guess it depends on what you intend to do with the strings, but at least it's simple!

Comment: Thanks so much, Chris! - I get the question wasn't well stated, but, given your solution (very clean and simple) I just end up with an array of BitArray... Also very easy to work with!