# C# Looking for a more efficient means of storing and comparing lists of true/false values

Tags: c#, list, boolean, comparison, bitwise-and

I have datasets with lists of true/false values. These lists can be of any length, but typically will vary between 5 and 40 items in length in most cases. Within each dataset all lists will be of the same length. For the purposes of this process, the elements in a list, once created, will always be in the same order (i.e. once a list has been set to true, false, false, true, it will always be true, false, false, true).

I also need to be able to quickly compare any two of these lists of equal length for inequality (i.e. same values in same order). By inequality in this case I mean that the slots that are true for one dataset cannot have any matching true values in the same slots in the other dataset. False values are irrelevant. For example:

- 10010 and 10001 are "equal" because the first slot on both values is
  true
- 00100 and 00001 are "not equal" because none of the true values
  fall in the same slot
- 00000 and 00000 are also "not equal" because
  neither has any true values

The comparisons will be done over and over again and need to be done in the fastest and most memory efficient way possible. The initial creation process will only run once for a given dataset so efficiency there is secondary to the comparison process.

I've tried arrays and sorted lists of booleans doing a position by position bool comparison as well as strings ("100101" format) doing a for loop position char value comparison. But it seems like there should be a more processor and memory efficient manner to store and compare these lists of values.

Example of the string compare version. The array and list compares followed the same pattern:

```
private bool DoListsConflict(string activeValuesA, string activeValuesB)
{
     var lengths = new int[3] {10000, activeValuesA.Length, activeValuesB.Length};

     var a = activeValuesA.ToCharArray();
     var b = activeValuesB.ToCharArray();

     for (var x = 0; x < lengths.Min(); x++)
     {
         if (a[x] == '1' && b[x] == '1') return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36013006/best-way-to-store-multiple-lists-of-true-false-values) whose answer suggests BitArrays, but the suggested answer also states that it isn't necessarily efficient and I don't know that this would be any better than what I'm already doing. Are there more efficient structures I can use to speed up the overall process?

Comment: show code, some effort to see more efficient than what.

Comment: I didn't add code because I felt I clearly explained my current flow in the next to last paragraph. If it's beneficial for someone to see me post a for loop or two iterating through a pair of arrays or lists comparing values that's been seen millions of times across the web, I'll be happy to do so.

Comment: Added code example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do bitwise AND and check whether you get zero or non-zero value.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I think I see it. I've tried to avoid bitwise calcs in the past. So, if I understand, store each list as a number (uint or ulong) and just do a bitwise AND compare between each number. If the result is a non-zero value, there's a conflict.  Correct???    

The only exception would be if both lists are 0 values. But I could do an initial check for that case before doing the bitwise AND.

Answer (score 0):

The best and efficient way for doing this is working with bits. A bit is the smaller data size in a computar and it is the most efficient too, because you can use the ULA to manipulate it in less than one machine clock cycle (when working with the CPU pipeline full).

For this, I created the simple class below that I called BooleanSet. It can store any number of boolean values using the smallest amount of memory possible and a minimum amount of CPU time:

```
    public class BooleanSet
{
    private List<ulong> values = new List<ulong>();
    private int count = 0;
    /* 0x8000000000000000UL is the same as the binary number 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 */
    private const ulong MsbFilterMask = 0x8000000000000000UL;
    /* 0xfffffffffffffffeUL is the same as the binary number 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110 */
    private const ulong LsbEraserMask = 0xfffffffffffffffeUL;
    public BooleanSet()
    {
        /* the set mut be initialized with a 0 value */
        values.Add(0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Append a new boolean value to the list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newValue">New value to append</param>
    public void Append(bool newValue)
    {
        /* Each element in list can store up to 64 boolean values.
         * If is number is going to be overcome, the set must grow up.
         */
        if (count % 64 == 63)
        {
            values.Add(0);
        }
        count++;
        /* now  we just have to shift the whole thing left, but we have
         * to preserve the MSB for lower elements:
         * 
         * We have to initialize the last MSB (Most Significant Bit) with the new value.
         */
        ulong lastMsb = newValue ? 0x1UL : 0x0UL;

        for (int position = 0; position < values.Count; position++)
        {
            /* & is the bitwhise operator AND
             * It is used as a mask to zero fill anything, except the MSB;
             * After get the MSB isolated, we just have to shift it to right edge (shift right 63 times)
             */
            ulong currentMsb = (values[position] & MsbFilterMask) >> 63;
            /* Now we have discart MSB and append a new LSB (Less Significant Bit) to the current value.
             * The | operator is the bitwise OR
             */
            values[position] = ((values[position] << 1) & LsbEraserMask) | lastMsb;
            lastMsb = currentMsb;
        }
        /* We don't have to take care of the last value, because we have did this already (3 1sf lines of this methid) */
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        /* Now we have to write the set as a string */
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        /* We have to keep track of the total item count */
        int totalCount = count;
        string separator = "";
        foreach (ulong value in this.values)
        {
            /* for each value in the internal list, we have to create a new bit mask */
            ulong bitMask = 1;
            /* We have to get all bits of all values, except the last one, because it may not be full.
             * the totalCount will let us to know where we reach the end of the list.
             */
            for (int pos = 0; pos < 64 && totalCount > 0; pos++, totalCount--)
            {
                /* We have to write the string in reverse order, because the first item is in the end of our list */
                sb.Insert(0, separator);
                sb.Insert(0, (value & bitMask) > 0);
                separator = ", ";
                bitMask = bitMask << 1;
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

This class has only 2 methods:
 1: Append(), for adding new values to the set.
 2: ToString(), for listing all stored values in the same order it was added.

For testing this example, just create a console application like this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BooleanSet set = new BooleanSet();
        set.Append(false);
        set.Append(false);
        set.Append(true);
        set.Append(false);
        set.Append(true);
        set.Append(false);
        set.Append(true);

        Console.WriteLine("Checking the stored values:");
        Console.WriteLine(set.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Checking the stored values again:");
        Console.WriteLine(set.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The output will be like this:

---

> Checking the stored values:
>   False, False, True, False, True, False, True
>
> Checking the stored values again:
>   False, False, True, False, True, False, True
>
> Press any key to continue...

---

For comparing two set you just have to compare the values inside thir inner lists the way you want.